# What is a synonym for bad writing?

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

I am looking for a word to reflect what a novice author would use to describe his own writing (somewhat derogatorily). My first thought was **drivel**.

Comment: Did you mean drivel?

Comment: I think I did. Although that rings closer to "silly" than "bad quality". Any other ideas?

Comment: 'Silly' would be 'bad quality'. But you haven't explained whether you want a term for bad handwriting or bad authorship (hence the different answers below).

Comment: You should edit your question, and change dribble to drivel. You'll probably get more answers as a result.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments in this answer. They've helped me form a clearer picture about how this online community works.

Comment: Tabloid journalism?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hack (hackwork), drek, schlock, pulp, sludge (only because fiction magazine editors call the mass of submissions that come over the transom the "sludge pile").

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps the word you are looking for is *[scrawl](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/scrawl)*

> v.tr. To write hastily or illegibly.
>
> v.intr. To write in a sprawling, irregular manner.
>
> n.
>
> 1. Irregular, often illegible handwriting.
> 2. Something, such as a note, written hastily or illegibly.

Answer (score 2):

#### *[scribble](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/scribble)*

> His awful writing is nothing but scribbles.

#### *[doodle](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/doodle)*

> *And yet, the film works in spite of all its cute writerly and aesthetic doodling.*

The examples are [googlable](http://www.wordnik.com/words/googlable).

Comment: My disagreement here is that these are examples of a critic's creative literary license in colorfully, somewhat playfully, chastising the writer's work. I don't take them as substantive synonyms for "bad writing" that would stand on their own outside the context of their respective critiques.

Comment: @JohnM.Landsberg I have no quibble with your opinion that these are not substantive synonyms for bad writing, because we share that opinion. But I do hope you're not disagreeing with my including them here. I wasn't going by the title of this q, but by what OP had written: "I'm thinking dribble." I thought scribble and doodle would be right on par with dribble. I was really only trying to be helpful to him; he obviously needed a derrogatory word. Also, I don't think my suggestions are, for most uses, as good as yours (one of those upvotes was mine).But what if someone just needs sth different?

Comment: Plus, they follow the same phonological shtik: dribble shlock sludge doodle scribble. Their meaning is almost less important than their onomatopoeic potential (when that's what an author wants to go for).

Comment: In fact you're quite correct, and I didn't intend "disagreement" to be a harsh assessment. Nor did I downvote, because I don't disagree with you including them here. Your thinking is in line with mine. And by the way, I'll take this opportunity to mention I've taken note of your other answers, which are remarkable, to say the least. I would be more than fascinated to see what your profile would say, if you were to fill it in!

Answer (score 2):

It's called ***cacography.***

[defined](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/cacography?s=t) as:

> bad handwriting; poor penmanship.

Answer (score 2):

I have pretty bad handwriting. Once a person called my handwriting 'chicken-scratch'. That sounded appropriate for bad handwriting.

Comment: LOL `chicken-scratch`. I just used your jargon for a secondary school student ;)

Answer (score 1):

Amateurish writing is used to describe a style of writing that is poor.

Answer (score 1):

Doggerel. I don’t know if anyone applies the word to his or her own writing, but it’s a good word for other people’s tripe.

Answer (score 0):

I'd call bad writing *trash* or *garbage*.

Not exactly relevant to your question though fits the topic: in Russian we call bad writing *макулатура* (wastepaper).

Comment: In one English article, I saw the word maculature being used to describe bad writing. It should be of no surprise that English has the word; macula is Latin for stain.

Comment: Thank you, @Talia, I was wondering whether this word is used the same way in English.

Comment: According to Webster's, it's not: **Maculature**

Mac"u*la*ture\, n. Blotting paper. [Obs.] See the Ngram at http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=drivel%2Cscrawl%2Cmaculature&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3&share= to decide on whether 'this word is [really] used the same way in English'.

Comment: I see your point, @Edwin. Exactly this definition one will find in any academic Russian dictionary—blotting paper, that is. ...Which doesn't stop anyone from using the word meaning *blotting paper* figuratively to describe a piece of bad writing.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Ngram doesn't show it, but the secondary, figurative, derrogatory meaning of maculature does exist in English. The article I've read is not the only example of such use, here's a few more:

Comment: [A hopless and feeble attempt ... typical bad historical revisionism. ... fanatical pro-homosexual point of view. A typical form of pseudoscience serving a "higher cause". Put it on your bookshelf together with works of Marxist-soviet apologists or the "Protocols of the wise of sion". Or better put it into the maculature box. ](http://www.amazon.com/Christianity-Social-Tolerance-Homosexuality-Fourteenth/product-reviews/0226067114?pageNumber=4)

Comment: [Time to forget the maculature that lures you into buying stuff you don’t need by making you feel somehow defective.](http://alteressence.com/2013/04/30/the-naked-truth-about-style/#.UkAAERDbK5I) [link3](http://books.google.ba/books?id=NdaSqYCfZFIC&pg=PA177&lpg=PA177&dq="maculature"&source=bl) About that link3, octavo is a small format for books, usually pulp.

Comment: @Talia Ford: 'Maculature' gets only slightly more Google hits than 'mirbane', about which a dictionary I've still got says 'this is apparently a meaningless word'. I can find no dictionaries willing to support the 'tripe' sense - Collins and AHD don't even list the word. I wouldn't leave Mykola possibly thinking that 'this word is used the same way in English' because of a few maverick examples on the web.